# Add new key-value pair in python dict

Tags: python, mongodb

I am facing problem while trying to add a new key-value pair in python dictionary while keeping previous key-value pairs. I am using `MongoDB` as database.

My Sample response is

```
"field1" : "a",
"field2" : "b",
"field3" : "c",
"history" : {
    "2019-09-03 00:00:00" : "state1"
}
```

Expected response is

```
"field1" : "a",
"field2" : "b",
"field3" : "c",
"history" : {
    "2019-09-01 00:00:00" : "state1"
    "2019-09-02 00:00:00" : "state1"
    "2019-09-03 00:00:00" : "state1"
}
```

I want to add key-value pair in history, the key is date and value will be state but the problem is my code removes the previous key-value pairs and then add a new key-value pair.

I am using `mongo client` to save a record in MongoDB data.

here is my code

```
out = dict()
history = dict()
out['field1'] = 'a'
out['filed2'] = 'b'
out['field3'] = 'c'
history[str(datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0))] = 'state1'
out_handle.update_one(
                    {'field1': a, 'field2': 'b', 'field3': 'c'},
                    {'$set': out}},
                    upsert=True
                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you wish to query by the three fields `{'field1': a, 'field2': 'b', 'field3': 'c'}` and then just add a history record.  Do so with the `$push` operator.  Note the second arg to `update_one` can have `$push` and `$set` and `$unset` operators.

```
coll.update_one({'field1': a, 'field2': 'b', 'field3': 'c'}, {
        "$push": {"history":{"D2":"S3"}},
        "$set": {"otherField1": "hello", "otherField2": "goodbye"}
        }, upsert=True)
```

**BUT**
I highly recommend you do not use dates as keys but rather as value, and as real datetime values, not strings.  It is much easier to deal with date queries when they are a value an not a key, e.g.

```
rec = {
    "date": datetime.datetime.now(),
    "state": "state1"  # or whatever
}
coll.update_one({'field1': a, 'field2': 'b', 'field3': 'c'}, {"$push": {"history":rec}} )
```

This yields something like:

```
{
    "field1" : "a",
    "field2" : "b",
    "field3" : "c",
    "history" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-09-03T07:54:38.144Z"),
            "state" : "state1"
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-09-03T07:54:38.144Z"),
            "state" : "state2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have one more DictField other than `history` so i am using `'$set':out`, but if I use `set` and `push` together I am getting error `TypeError: update_one() got multiple values for argument 'upsert'`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solution:

create sub-dictionary to insert inside parent dictionary:

```
    history[str(datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, day=1))] = 'state1'
    history[str(datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, day=2))] = 'state1'
    history[str(datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, day=3))] = 'state1'
```

insert sub dictionary inside parent 'out' dictionaty

```
    out['history']=history
```

effect

```
    {'field1': 'a',
    'filed2': 'b',
    'field3': 'c',
    'history': {'2019-09-03 00:00:00': 'state1',
    '2019-09-02 00:00:00': 'state1',
    '2019-09-01 00:00:00': 'state1'}}
```